# how to pass a label to POST

Tags: php, variables, session, post

Im currently filling a label with a session variable, however i need to use the label data later (send it to another label), or create a new session to do so. However, when i attempt to access the first label, or the session that ive set its tells me its not set. So im assuming the data in the first label is showing but its not actually there?

//this is how im creating the first label

```
<?php

  include_once "dbcon.php";

  //PERFORMING CHECK IF ALL REQUIRED SESSION VARIABLES ARE SET
  if (isset($_SESSION['s_score1'], $_SESSION['s_score2'], $_SESSION['t_team1'], $_SESSION['t_team2'])) {
    $team1 = $_SESSION['t_team1'];
    $team2 = $_SESSION['t_team2'];
    $score1 = $_SESSION['s_score1'];
    $score2 = $_SESSION['s_score2'];

    if ($score1 == $score2) {
      header("Location: tables.php?table=draw"); //CHECKS IF MATCH IS A DRAW, CANNOT BE A DRAW
      exit();
    }else {
      if ($score1 > $score2){
        echo $_SESSION['t_team1'];
      }else {
        echo $_SESSION['t_team2'];

      }
    }
  }else {
  echo "-";
}
?>
```

//this is how im printing it

```
<label name="round2-team1" class="round2-teams">
          <?php include_once "action/winner-script.php";?>
        </label>
```

the issue appears when i try to use this label above, creating a session variable with it, or moving it to a new label is impossible, its like it doesnt exist, even though i can see it on the page???

```
<?php

  include_once "dbcon.php";

  //PERFORMING CHECK IF ALL REQUIRED SESSION VARIABLES ARE SET
  if (isset($_SESSION['s_score9'], $_SESSION['s_score10'], $_SESSION['t_team9'], $_SESSION['t_team10'])) {
    $team1 = $_SESSION['t_team9'];
    $team2 = $_SESSION['t_team10'];
    $score1 = $_SESSION['s_score9'];
    $score2 = $_SESSION['s_score10'];

    if ($score1 == $score2) {
      header("Location: tables.php?table=draw"); //CHECKS IF MATCH IS A DRAW, CANNOT BE A DRAW
      exit();
    }else {
      if ($score1 > $score2){
        echo $_SESSION['t_team9'];
      }else {
        echo $_SESSION['t_team10'];

      }
    }
  }else {
  echo "-";
}
?>
```

This is the script, here i am taking my two labels that are displaying on the page, im determining the winner, and then im displaying the session variable which won the game in a different label on the same page. however, when i try using

```
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['t_team9'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['t_team9'];
}else {
  echo "somethings wrong";
}
  ?>
```

anywhere on the page where my labels lie, i just get the error something went wrong

ATTEMPTED FIX:

```
<?php

  include_once "dbcon.php";

  //PERFORMING CHECK IF ALL REQUIRED SESSION VARIABLES ARE SET
  if (isset($_SESSION['s_score13'], $_SESSION['s_score14'], $_SESSION['result'], $_SESSION['result2'])) {
    $team1 = $_SESSION['result'];
    $team2 = $_SESSION['result2'];
    $score1 = $_SESSION['s_score13'];
    $score2 = $_SESSION['s_score14'];

    if ($score1 == $score2) {
      header("Location: tables.php?table=draw"); //CHECKS IF MATCH IS A DRAW, CANNOT BE A DRAW
      exit();
    }else {
      if ($score1 > $score2){
        $team1 = $_SESSION['result'];
        $_SESSION['result5'] = $team1;
      }else {
        $team2 = $_SESSION['result2'];
        $_SESSION['result5'] = $team2;

      }
    }
  }else {
  echo "-";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you declaring session_start() at the beginning of every page? If you don't then the session is just forgotten.

Comment: Yes im pretty sure. Like i said, i can see the session on the page, but when i try to use it somewhere else, its just not set or something?

Comment: if i place it at the top of the php script ive included i get an error that a session is already set

Comment: On the `round2-team1` the label is getting the session value properly? Your problem is that if you try `echo $_SESSION['t_team1']` on another page it isnt displaying?

Comment: Yes, however, im trying to display it on the same page in a different label, im just running it through a script first to determine if it should be displayed. I can include this script if it will help, but its very similar to the one already included?

Comment: Can you post the script? The more we have to work with the better we can help you I guess

Comment: ive updated with all the code i believe is relevant, ive been trying to solve this all day so i appreciate the help